# How to Block Banking Transaction SMS in android programatically

Tags: android, sms

I want to create an app that can block all the bank transaction SMS, so that user can not find that some transaction has been done from his bank account. This is just a part of my Project. If anyone has any idea, kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an amazing app idea.

Answer (score 1):

For android kitkat+ versions, only the default SMS app is able to write to the SMS Provider and only the default SMS app receives the SMS_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast when the user receives an SMS. 
First you will need to give an option to set the app as default SMS app and create a BroadcastReceiver, include an intent filter for [SMS_DELIVER_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_DELIVER_ACTION)
The broadcast receiver will receive the incoming sms, then it is upto the application whether to write the message or not.